# Magento 2 customer_register_success not working

Tags: magento2.2.2

I want to get customer id after new customer register successfully in Magento 2.2.2.
In app/code/vendor/module/etc/frontend/events.xml-> I added this code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_register_success">
        <observer name="update_customer_referal_code" instance="vendor\module\Observer\UpdateCustomerMeta" />
    </event>
</config>
```

and in app/code/vendor/module/Observer/UpdateCustomerMeta.php -> I have added this

```
<?php

namespace vendor\module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class UpdateCustomerMeta implements ObserverInterface
{

    protected $_customerRepositoryInterface;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface
    ) {
        $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        print_r($customer->getId());
        echo "if this string shows it means observer works";
        exit();
    }
}
```

but when I register a user it directly goes to customer panel after registering anyone please tell what mistake I am making.

Comment: I am amazed that no one from the community reacts so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tested your code in a Magento2.2 installation and it works

[image]

I assume you have a well registered working module named **vendor_module**

So I suspect maybe there is a typo when you say **vendor\module**, are your module name & folders really lowercase?

If there are no typo error, have you run both `bin/magento setup:upgrade` & `bin/magento setup:di:compile` commands?

If we've reached here, then the only explanation is you have some 3rd party extension installed, which is causing **customer_register_success** event not to be fired

Comment: I need more help

Comment: so? what do you need?

Comment: I have a new field in customer register form named referral_code i just want to get this field data in my UpdateCustomerMeta observer how can i get the value of the field "referral_code"

Comment: I think the best would be to create a new question for that

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/219223/magento-2-observer-customer-register-success

Comment: Ok, I have answered it

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the path of your event.

Customer registration is the common event for frontend and backend.

So your event path should be `app/code/vendor/module/etc/events.xml`

Comment: frontend is working fine

Comment: yes you are right but i just want this for frontend