# Magento 2 Observer customer_register_success

Tags: magento2.2.2

I have a new field in customer register form named referral_code i just want to get this field data in my UpdateCustomerMeta observer how can i get the value of the field "referral_code" in observer of customer_register_success

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that event you can access controller (and so, any parameter submitted)

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch(
    'customer_register_success',
    ['account_controller' => $this, 'customer' => $customer]
);
```

So I think you should be able to get the request parameters this way...

```
$parameters = $observer->getEvent()->getAccountController()->getRequest()->getParams();
```

Comment: it shows all parameter how to get only referal_code thanks in advance.
After that i will mark your ans

Comment: Instead of getParams() use getParam('your_parameter_here')

Comment: Awesome Thank you